# Script not running from crontab but running from terminal?

Tags: 12.04, python, cron

The script is running from terminal but not from crontab.The script code and error i am getting is written below :

**Cronjob**

```
*/5 * * * * cd /root/; python mkdir.py
```

**Script**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['touch','yahoo.txt'])
```

**Error from Crontab mail**

```
From root@vps.server.com  Mon Jul 22 21:10:05 2013
Return-Path: <root@vps.server.com>
Received: from vps.server.com (localhost [127.0.0.1])
    by vps.server.com (8.14.4/8.14.4/Debian-2ubuntu2) with ESMTP id r6MHA3ll002017
    for <root@vps.server.com>; Mon, 22 Jul 2013 21:10:03 +0400
Received: (from root@localhost)
    by vps.server.com (8.14.4/8.14.4/Submit) id r6MHA1sr002016
    for root; Mon, 22 Jul 2013 21:10:01 +0400
Date: Mon, 22 Jul 2013 21:10:01 +0400
Message-Id: <201307221710.r6MHA1sr002016@vps.server.com>
From: root@vps.server.com (Cron Daemon)
To: root@vps.server.com
Subject: Cron <root@vps> cd /root/; python mkdir.py
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ANSI_X3.4-1968
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/root>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=root>

': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Could you please post the relevant line in your crontab? (Please edit your question)

Answer (score 2):

Your 'mkdir.py' script is not in a location that is visible to your current path.
You can see the places that cron/sh are looking in the error message mail:
`X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>`
This means that anything not qualified with a directory needs to be in either `/usr/bin` or `/bin`. Python is in one of those directories (or else cron would say something like "command not found: python"), mkdir.py is not.

**A simple fix:** Try changing your crontab entry to:
`python /path/to/mkdir.py`

**A more involved fix:** Since you have '#!/usr/bin/python' in your script you do not need to explicitly invoke python in order to execute it; you could give it execute permissions via `chmod +x mkdir.py` and then copy it to `/usr/bin`.

Changing your crontab entry to `mkdir.py` should work once you have moved the executable script to the correct location.